# Can't Detect and Backup Flashdisk Drive

Tags: usb, mount, backup, usb-drive

I have a flashdisk drive that can't mount or backup, but when I check with `lsusb` that flashdisk is detected:

```
➜  ~ lsusb        
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c18 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But, if it is detected then  why doesn't my flashdisk exist in `/dev/sdb`? Does anyone know what happened to my flashdisk?

```
➜  ~ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00094cd3

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 195311615 195309568  93,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       195313662 199311359   3997698   1,9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       199313408 942567423 743254016 354,4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       942569472 976773167  34203696  16,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5       195313664 199311359   3997696   1,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

➜  ~ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD5000LPVT-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  100GB  100GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      100GB   102GB  2047MB  extended
 5      100GB   102GB  2047MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 3      102GB   483GB  381GB   primary   ext4
 4      483GB   500GB  17,5GB  primary   ext4

➜  ~ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  93,1G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 354,4G  0 part /media/agaust/Data
├─sda4   8:4    0  16,3G  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   1,9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I also tried to check it via Disks:

[image: usb drive]

Comment: would another flash drive work?

Comment: @Camden yes, another flash drive works properly..

Comment: will the flashdisk work in another computer

Comment: nope.. this flaskdisk doesn't work in another computers..

Comment: has it worked before?

Comment: Based on what you've posted, I'd be inclined to say that it may be a dud drive. Especially since it refuses to work on another computer as well. Either that, or you may need to rewrite the MBR/GPT record...

Comment: @ThatGuy Is it possible this flashdisk is infected to the virus?

Comment: Unlikely that is the cause. Flash memory breaks down over time, it's also susceptible to electrical damage. Power surge could have done it. Corrupted firmware, any number of things. But it definitely doesn't look good.

Comment: This problem (and/or related problems) is described at the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Comment: @sudodus great catch on that answer. Maybe flag this as a duplicate?

Comment: no cuz its a broken drive